# How to deploy my Spring Boot project on Jenkins?

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, spring-boot, web-deployment

I am trying to create a deploy job in Jenkins for my Spring Boot - Maven project. These are the steps i have followed until now:

- Click New Item
- Give a name, and choose Maven project
- Configuration page opens
- In Source Code Management, i have given my Git repository URL
- In Build section under Goals and options i have written "spring-boot:run"
- Saved and applied

Now when i click "Build Now", it checks out the project, builds and deploys. But the job does not end. This is the last line in the console output screen:

```
: Started Application in 4.737 seconds (JVM running for 16.297)
```

[image]

What is my problem? I need a simple step by step guidance since i do not have any Jenkins experience.

EDIT: I do not know what post build action is which is mentioned in the other post. I need a simple step by step guidance since i do not have any Jenkins experience.

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy SpringBoot Maven application with Jenkins ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500066/how-to-deploy-springboot-maven-application-with-jenkins)

Comment: Spring Boot 1.2.2.RELEASE.

Comment: The question is similar but the problem is different i think. I have seen that question and tried the answers.. did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

The job doesn't end because your application is up and running on embeeded Tomcat. It's normal behaviour and you should be able to use your application at this point.

---

If you want to make another build, you should stop current build before starting a new one. To do this automaticaly (e.g. when your master branch is changed) you can create another one job.

Example of a job that triggers build of a main job:

- Create a 'Freestyle project' in Jenkins;
- Fill 'Source Code Management': your Repository URL and Credentials,      Branches to build - `*/master`;
- Fill 'Build Triggers': select 'Poll SCM' and type `H/2 * * * *` in 'Shedule' to poll repository every 2 minutes;
- Fill 'Build': add build step 'Execute shell' and type next commands to stop current build and start a new one (don't forget to replace JENKINS_URL and JOB_NAME with your values) -

  ```
  curl -X POST http://JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/lastBuild/stop;
  curl -X POST http://JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build;
  ```
- Save your job :)

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, just wanted to add that you may need the following two steps:
1. in global security settings -->  Uncheck "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" 
2. add your username and password to the curls:

curl -X POST http://JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/lastBuild/stop --user kaito:123456;
curl -X POST http://JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build --userkaito:123456;

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are going to deploy the `spring-boot` application in another server different to jenkins server you need to build your app `mvn clean package` and to move the `jar` created from jenkins server to the new server then you can use another step to start the app using `java -jar myapp.jar`. But, if you are going to deploy in tomcat server then you can use tomcat-api to deploy remotely.

Comment: Where are you going to deploy your spring-boot app?

Comment: On my own server using Jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins is for the continuous integration. I don't want to build my jar, and then deploy separately everytime i have a change..  Jenkins make almost everything. I just want that my job ends properly.

Comment: spring-boot:run just starts the application, so the job will end, if you stop the application.

Comment: Stop the application? How?