# Spring Boot - Jenkins CICD

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a sample for Spring Boot-GitHub-Jenkins Auto deploy using the web hooks from Github.
the first deployment goes through fine and the created Jar is invoked, when I push the code again the web hook triggers the Jenkins but as the Jar is  already running it gives the me the below error, have tried searching but unable to find the excat solution i.e. windows script for to be executed before SCM build which would stop the Jar and allow a new build.
Configuration used:
Execute Windows batch Command:
gradle build --info
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestRepo\build\libs
start /min java -jar gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar

Have also tried with step: Run build steps before SCM:
command to kill the process: for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":9000" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a

I am using port 9000 for tomcat.
Error: 
Wiping out workspace first.
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestRepo\build\libs\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:318)
at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:274)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: are you using linux server to run your jar file ?

Comment: No it's on my local windows, I have installed Jenkins and trying to make this work

Comment: Your idea is correct.l But your batch code i dont thing is correct. You should kill using .java and not using process ID, because process id changes on every run. So just make sure that your command is actually killing the process before putting it in jenkins

Comment: Thanks. But i am killing the process after identifying the process id which is running on port 9000. That command works fine on my local but when I give this in jenkins and configure it run before the scm build still i m getting above error. So if jar is already deployed the jenkin is not allowing to build or stop the jar i guess.

Comment: are you running as a batch file from jenkins?

Comment: I have given the above command in build configuration for the job. So there are 2 windows batch commands configured: 1. To kill the existing running process and 2. To build and deploy the new jar.

Comment: you might need to see this answer , i tried locally and it worked fine but i didnt use you batch command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437774/how-to-deploy-my-spring-boot-project-on-jenkins

Comment: Thanks this got resolved, the problem was with the syntax command to kill the process, got to know after searching lot of blogs. It should be “%%a” when we run it in batch file. Thanks for the suggestion to look into the command.