# How to deploy multiple SpringBoot environments with Jenkins?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, gradle, spring-boot

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500066/how-to-deploy-springboot-maven-application-with-jenkins) I have created my Jenkins builds with which I start the tomcat servers from spring boot with gradle.

What I want to achieve is to have different builds for different environments (e.g. production, user acceptance testing, development). To do this I am creating multiple jenkins builds: one for development and one for uat for this example. A war file is being created from the project and then I run this command to start the new server: `echo "fuser -k 8090/tcp ; java -jar '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/VCrawl UAT Build/workspace/build/libs/vcrawl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war' --spring.profiles.active=uat" | at now`

The problem is that when one builds finished and this command is being executed by the shell, the other server stops in order to start this one. My hunch is that Jenkins can only use one shell terminal, therefore when I run one, the other shell will stop running, therefore stopping the other server.

If I start the servers from the machine on which Jenkins is running there is no problem, both servers work.

Also, I want to specify that the environments run on separate ports, use separate database and so on.

How to create two tomcat servers running at the same time from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the spring boot war-file as a service, it won't be killed when the command is executed.

Take a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service)