# Run a springboot jar with Jenkins Build command

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins

I am trying to automate a `SpringBoot Application` through `Jenkins`.

I have `myApp.jar` and currently, I run it using the following command

```
nohup java -jar myApp.jar &
```

Press `Ctrl^C` or `Ctrl^Z` and process keep running in the background.

Logs will be added in `nohup.out`

Now I want the same process to be done using Jenkins.

In Jenkins, build section, I have selected **Execute Shell Script** with the above command.

When build is triggered. I can see Application startup Log in Jenkins Log but **the problem is, build never finishes.**

I have tried

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe timeout --foreground 30 nohup java -jar website-status.jar &
```

also

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup java -jar website-status.jar &
```

`timeout` is killing the process. I don't want process to be killed.

**Edit 1:**

I have tried this as well. Build keeps running.

```
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe nohup java -jar website-status.jar &
```

Comment: Have you checked this issue ? https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/running-a-background-process-in-pipeline-job Could be helpful.

Comment: Tried. Same result. Build keeps running

Comment: Same questions  with answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500066/how-to-deploy-springboot-maven-application-with-jenkins/28501714 

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Managing-a-Spring-Boot-self-executable-application-td4720491.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we execute command like this

```
nohup java -jar myApp.jar &
```

a prompt is shown saying log will be written in `nohup.out` file and this was causing the script to hang forever in Jenkins.

I changed the command and now no prompt and works fine, logs are written in `server.log`

```
nohup java  -jar myApp.jar >> server.log 2>&1&
```